# Can you call a base contract's fallback function?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

Can you call the fallback function of the base contract that the current contract is inherited from?

```
contract LittleA {
  function() {
    doLittleStuff();

    // how do I call the base contract's fallback function?
  }
}

contract A {
  function() {
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call things like `super()` or `A()` so you have no way to call the unnamed fallback function.

However, **if you can modify the parent contract**, you can move all the logic of your fallback function to another named function that would be called from the callback in `A` and that would be callable from `LittleA`.

Here is an exemple with two contracts named Parent and Child. The `fallback()` function can be called from Child using `super.fallback()`.

```
contract Parent{
  function fallback() internal {
    log0("Parent fallback function");
  }

  function (){
     fallback();
  }
}

contract Child is Parent {
  function (){
    log0("child fallback function");
    super.fallback();
  }
}
```

Sending a basic transaction to `Child` contract will call its fallback function which calls `Parent.fallback()` using. The result is :

```
LOG (Child): child fallback function
LOG (Child): Parent fallback function
```

I admit that this not the most beautiful design but as you set the visibility of `fallback()` to `internal`, it's not visible into the ABI so you're good.

Comment: Also note that you could simply call the parent contract using the call() function. But you would have to know contract address. Also note that having too much logic in the fallback functions seems to be discouraged because a tx that reach fallback may not have enough gas for complex operations, most of the time it's a regular ether send transaction : https://github.com/ConsenSys/Ethereum-Development-Best-Practices/wiki/Fallback-functions-and-the-fundamental-limitations-of-using-send()-in-Ethereum-&-Solidity

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good answer. One question though: isn't the contract address just `this`?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want to do with "this". This is a self reference, how would you want to use it there?

Comment: `this` is explicitly convertible to an `address` type. It is the address of the contract. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html

Comment: @Raine do you mean using inheritance to get the parent address using this to then call the fallback using this address?

Comment: Yes. You mentioned that "you could simply call the parent contract using the call() function." Then you said "you would have to know contract address." I pointed out that we *do* know the contract address... it's just `this`. I'm not "using inheritance" to accomplish this; inheritance is a given, and I was just wondering if there was a way to invoke the fallback function of the parent contract. Hope that helps to clarify! I'm still interested in your suggestion about using the call function, things just got confusing when we began discussing the contract address.

Comment: @Raine I'll try but I think that "this" will only give the child contract address if it works like in other oop languages.

Comment: I tried (see https://gist.github.com/NicolasMassart/64e4be53123183fca599f8394aeb129c ) and I confirm that "this" won't give you the parent address.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out! It is clear we are testing different things now. If you deploy a child contract and then deploy a parent contract on its own, then yes they have different addresses. That has nothing to do with inheritance though. If you have a child contract that inherits from a parent contract, then when you access `this` from a function on either the parent contract or the child contract *of the deployed child*, you will get the same address. This is demonstrated here: https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#gist=19c667c2a30e44d3ef4dd2b05e8e3de8&version=soljson-latest.js